# organizing script files for different pages in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Let us say i have two pages based on `laravel` and I have different script files for both the pages.Now I am loading all the scripts in `index.blade.php`.As per the present implementation all the scripts are loaded in both cases.How to load different script files for different pages and also load scripts after the html.

Comment: by *pages*: do you mean **views** or **applications**? And what kind of scripts? JS?

Comment: use something like `requirejs` ?

Comment: @nozzleman yes it uses two different views and the script are js files

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) which was stated as an alternative by @jsxqf in the comments.

I personally have  `yields` in my master-layout (one for `js`, one for `css`) which i am adressing using blade. In your `views`, you could do the same.

**File** `layout/master.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    @yield('css-scripts')
  </head>
  <body>
     @yield('content')
  </body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  @yield('js-scripts')
</html>
```

Your views would then extend this layout and put the scripts independently in the corresponding sections like so:

**File** `myview.blade.php`

```
@extends('layout.master')

@section('content')
    // your content...
@stop

@section('js-scripts')
    // here, you have control over additionally loaded scripts...
    <script src="otherscript.js"></script>
@stop
```

But it looks like require.js might be a good alternative to this approach, which i wasn't aware of until now.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach you can do is creating a section to put optional scripts using stack on your main layout

```
<html>
<head>

    <!-- At the end of head -->
    @stack('styles')

</head>
<body>
    <!-- At the end of body -->
    @stack('scripts')
   
</body>
</html>
```

In a normal view which would be your page,

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@push('styles')

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/page1.css')}}">

@endpush

@section('content')

    // page content

@endsection


@push('scripts')

    <script src="{{ asset('js/page1.js')}}"></script>

@endpush
```

This allows you to add additional optional scripts and styles to your main layout from other views, making it completely safe to organize styles / scripts in your views